# How to disable only zoom interactions in arction lightning chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, lightningchart

I would like to disable only the zoom interaction on the LightningChartJs but would still like to tap into the drag and other events.

But when I disable it(setMouseInteractionRectangleZoom) other interactions like drag dont run too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need more information. On my testing the all the events work fine when the mouse interactions have been disabled with "setMouseInteractionRectangleZoom(false)".

Comment: Hey I am using react and disable zoom interaction using a state and toggle it by using a ref to the chart.I could be implementing something wrong if you can please share a code where we can dynamically toggle zoom interactions in react

Comment: @Snekw please let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue with the library and was a flaw in my implementation

I was dynamically enabling and disabling zoom and other functionalities with state variables and the create chart function was inside useCallback hook and thus the chart had become unfunctional as the useCallback on change of state variables rerenders the function.

Apollogies to the team of LightningChartJs.